# Aligning text to the left, middle, right using span, text align, and inline-block, CSS, HTML

Tags: html, css

I have 4 divs. I have 3 divs inside of another div, and I'm trying to align them to the left, middle, and right while keeping them all on the same line. I've tried inline-block, but it's not working for some reason. I'm not sure what I did wrong, so please take a look at my code:

```css
 

#outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
#innerLeft {
    text-align:left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
#innerMiddle {
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
#innerRight {
    text-align:right;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
span {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id='outer'>
  <div id='innerLeft'><span>Left</span></div>
  <div id='innerMiddle'><span>Middle</span></div>
  <div id='innerRight'><span>Right</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So now today you want them all on the same line? yesterday they needed to be in different lines.

Comment: @j08691 I actually needed both but forgot to mention it yesterday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get them all on the same line you don't need the spans I suggested in your last question, but you do need to change the order of the divs. Then you just float the left and right elements to their respective sides.

```css
#outer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
}
#innerLeft {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#innerMiddle {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
#innerRight {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id='outer'>
  <div id='innerLeft'>Left</div>
  <div id='innerRight'>Right</div>

  <div id='innerMiddle'>Middle</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why does the order of the divs need to be changed?

Comment: Because you need to float the left and right divs out of the way so the middle div can float up between them.

Comment: You shouldn't have to change your markup. Just float them all left—check the fiddle in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

One method using your current structure is to give the wrapping div `position: relative` and the inner divs `position: absolute`

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1wgh0s16/)

Elements with `absolute` positioning are positioned relative to their first non `static` ancestor element. 
[CSS Position Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This is because in all the `divs` you are adding `width:100%` in you css which allows the `divs`to take all the width availabe with its `parent`.So despite `inline block` they are taking the whole width of there parent.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're setting the widths to 100%. They will take up 100% of the width of their containing element—hence one per line. Change the width to 33.33% and you'll get what you want.

If you're having issues with the borders, try using `box-sizing: border-box`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

```
#outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    box-sizing: border-box;//add this
}
#innerLeft {
    text-align:left;
}

#innerRight {
    text-align: right;
}

#innerMiddle {
    text-align: center;
}

#innerRight, #innerMiddle, #innerLeft {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.33%;//change this
    float: left;//add this (reliable way of getting rid of inline-block gap)
    box-sizing: border-box;//add this
}
span {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0wuzgcba/

Comment: You would also need to remove the white space added by displaying as inline-block.

Comment: Right. Updating Answer.